# 000 permission for a single file is not working well

Tags: permissions

I have set `000` permission for a single file writing this code:

```
sudo chmod 000 ./Desktop/*.gif
```

But still this file is deletable and renameable (but not readable).

Although this code:

```
sudo chmod 000 ./Desktop/Directory_name
```

makes the directory inaccessible (read,write,execution protected).

What's wrong ?

Comment: This is pretty well addressed in the Unix & Linux question [Why can rm remove read-only files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48579/80216)

Comment: P.S. I encourage you to avoid giving files names with asterisks in them; especially short ones like `*.gif`.  (Your question indicates that you have "a single file" called `*.gif`.)  Also, you don't need the `./` at the beginning of the pathname.

Comment: @G-Man, good suggestion. Actually I had only 1 .gif file in Desktop, So that selected a single file (I am sorry that, that is ambiguous for others)

Comment: You don't need to use `sudo` to change the permissions for your own files. Hence, `chmod 000 Desktop/*.gif` will do just as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> What's wrong?

Nothing. Removing all permissions from a file does not prevent deletion or renaming - those are controlled by the permissions of the containing directory (`Desktop`, in this case). If you want to prevent deletion or renaming, remove write permissions from the directory:

```
chmod a-w Desktop
```

Or make the files immutable:

```
sudo chattr +i Desktop/*.gif
```

`rm` will ask you if you want to delete an immutable file, but it can't:

```
$ rm foo
rm: remove write-protected regular file ‘foo’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘foo’: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Real-life analogy: you don't need to shoot someone in the head to remove them from the phone book.

Comment: Though people usually don't die from not being listed in any phone books.

Comment: @cjm I read it as a double-negative. Maybe I should have read that a few more times...